# Insert new row with values relating to existing rows

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to insert a new row where one of the columns is a function of the `MAX` of that column from the values that are already there. I know I can do this easily with PHP by setting a temporary variable and doing two queries, but I was just wondering if you can do this in pure MySQL.

First I tried this (note, the query contains much more, but this is what was messing up):

```
INSERT INTO tbl
(column_name)
VALUES (
    max( column_name ) + 6
)
```

Which produces the following error:

> 1111 Invalid use of group function

Then I tried:

```
INSERT INTO tbl
(column_name)
VALUES (
    ( SELECT max( column_name ) + 6 FROM tbl )
)
```

Which produces the following error:

> 1093 You can't specify target table 'tbl' for update in FROM clause

Comment: just take out values().  insert into table2 (columnname) select whatever from table1;

Comment: @developerwjk as I mentioned, I have many other things to insert. This is just one of the columns. There are about 20 columns all together in the query, but I only included one for simplicity.

Comment: @developerwjk part of the issue is this isn't table1 and table2, they are both table1

Comment: Check out the [INSEERT...SELECT syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-select.html).

Comment: @Mike: yes, but those can be literal values: `INSERT... SELECT MAX(col)+6,'literalstring',123,'2013-06-12' FROM tbl;`

Comment: @Wrikken ahh. Gotcha. Write that as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @user2532739: at least in mysql version 5.5 SELECTing from the same table your are INSERTing in is no proble,

Comment: @Wrikken I'm using 5.5.31

Comment: @Mike: yeah, the version comment was @ user2532739, as the problem was not that both are the same table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 INSERT INTO tbl (col, somecharcol, someintcol,somedatecol)
 SELECT MAX(col)+6,'literalstring',123,'2013-06-12' FROM tbl;
```

Comment: One question.. is there a way I can specify which columns to insert the values into? Or do I *have* to include all columns in `tbl` in their exact order?

Comment: Yes, edited it in, but also look at the link @boen_robot gave:[it's all in the the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-select.html)